# How does increasing the distance between 2 copper plates in a circuit affect the capacitance?

Tags: electricity, capacitance, voltage

We have been told that the voltage decreases, but not been given a proper explanation by my teacher. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Also, does increasing the distance between the plates of a capacitor decrease the capacitance, and hence reduce the time it takes for it to be discharged, since t=RC, and C gets smaller with a bigger distance between the plates?
Is my understanding of the above part correct?

Comment: Have you checked the list of links to the right under "Related" for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor is meant to store charges. **The ability to store how much charges is measured as the device's capacitance**. It is related to the voltage across the capacitor plates and the charge on the plates:

**C=Q/V**

Consider a parallel plate capacitor as shown:

[image]

Suppose initially the charge on the plate is zero. Now you connect it to an emf. The charges get accumulate on the plate in the same polarity as the emf. It takes some time for the plate to get charged to maximum charge Q. This charge on the plate induce a negative charge of same amount on the other plate.  In between the plates, we have a dielectric and let the separation distance of the plated be d.

Now **as we increase the area of the plates**, more charges can occupy the plates and hence increase it's ability to store charges, or increase it's capacitance. Since we have some charges on a surface, each plate develops electric field and this electric filed is equal and opposite for the two charged plates. A glance on the direction of these fields indicate that the net electric field exists only in between the plates while outside the plates, the net field vanishes. The net electric field inside the plate will be equal to twice that due to the individual plate, given by:

**E=σ/$ϵ_0 $**

where σ- surface charge density (Q/A)
$ϵ_0 $- permittivity of free space. In a medium of dielectric constant $ϵ_r$, the $ϵ_0$ has to be replaced by ϵ=$ϵ_r$$ϵ_0$

This electric field is constant throughout the space between the plates as you can see the field does not depends on the distance. Now the electric potential developed between the plates is nothing but the gradient of the electric field.

E=V/d

So we write

C=QE/d  or

C=$ϵ_0$A/d

which means that the capacitance of a plate is dependent on the distance between the plates.

*Or there is a simple way to remember this:*

On increasing the area of the plates, you could accommodate more charges on the plates and this in turn will increase the electric field between the plates. Increase in electric field between the plates means the voltage across the plates increase as E=V/d. Also the p.d between the plates increases with decrease in d. Hence we write, the capacitance as:

C∝$A/d$

The proportionality constant is the permittivity of the medium ϵ.

So, C=$ϵA/d$

A decrease in d corresponds to decrease in V (V=Ed) and increases the capacitance C.

Of course increase in C increases the time constant T=RC, if the discharge occurs through a resistor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still do not fully understand it. If I consider the equation E= -V/D for a uniform field, then V would increase with distance? Hence reducing the capacitance as C= Q/V.

Comment: The field between the plates is a constant. But if you reduce the distance of separation, the potential between the plate decreases (V=Ed). The negative sign guarantees only the flow of field between two points. V is the work done against the field. That's why there is a negative sign. So decrease in V corresponds to an increase in C as C=Q/V.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your first question, I suggest you look up "parallel plate capacitor" and see how the capacitance **C** relates to the inter-plate distance **d**.  To say more would risk violating the homework policy.

I cannot be sure what scenario your teacher was describing in which the voltage decreased.  In order to determine exactly what occurs when the plates of a capacitor are pulled apart, a full description of the initial state of the circuit in question would be needed.  For example, if the capacitor were connected directly to a battery, then the voltage across it would be unchanged, while if the capacitor were disconnected from all other components, then the voltage across it would actually increase.  Here is a link to another question which addresses some of these subtleties:
[The separation between the two plates of a capacitor is increased](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235958/the-separation-between-the-two-plates-of-a-capacitor-is-increased?rq=1)

Your last paragraph is qualitatively accurate, but I would warn you against using the notion of "the time a capacitor takes to discharge".  Capacitors discharge exponentially when connected to resistors.  Such an "RC" circuit's rate of discharge is often quantified by the "characteristic time", over which their charge is reduced by a factor of **e**.  There is no time at which one could look at the circuit and say "Okay, the capacitor is finished discharging NOW."